# Merge data-frames without specifying common columns with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Whats the `dplyr` way of accomplishing the following:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- tibble(a = c("a1","a2"), b = c("b1","b2") )
df2 <- tibble(c = c("c1","c2"), d = c("d1","d2") )
merge(df1, df2)
#    a  b  c  d
# 1 a1 b1 c1 d1
# 2 a2 b2 c1 d1
# 3 a1 b1 c2 d2
# 4 a2 b2 c2 d2
```

All the `dplyr` methods (`inner_join`, `outer_join`, etc) ask me for a common column in order to carry out the merging.

Is this not possible with `dplyr`?